# Identifying explicit intent purpose in Android, or building seperate activities?

Tags: java, android

This may be in the RTFM category but I can’t seem to figure out the proper way to do this. One of my activities shows some random data from a database, it uses some user-defined search-criteria from a previous activity to filter out which data blocks to search from. But it’s main purpose is to display the data, and present the user with a UI to manipulate the data to his will.

The user can also bookmark this random data, and then access it later again (the bookmarks show up in a listview in another activity). Rather than creating a whole new activity with basically the same purpose, I want to reuse the one already created, and just tell it that I want to view some data, rather than search for some new. So what is the proper way of informing an activity of want you want to do? Should that be defined in the Intent extras bundle or is there another way?

Or would the proper way be to create a new activity for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend the first Activity like this:

```
 ActivityB extends ActivityA
```

and then the methods that need to be different in `ActivityB` can `@override` the methods in `ActivityA`, but methods that do the same thing, you don't have to dupe as long as they're `protected`.

Comment: This would definetly work. I’m afraid my question may have been to specific, I’m looking for more of a guide-line for how I should structure my activities in future projects.

Comment: well what I described is known as polymorphism and can help you going forward to structure and architect not just your activities but all your code.